# Run python function from command line or subprocess popen

Tags: python, stdout

I wanted to run a test function called `test.counttest()` that counts up to 10.

```
def counttest():
    x = 0
    for x in range(0,3):
        x = x+1
        print("Number: "+ str(x))
        time.sleep(1)
```

I want to call **just the function** from the command line OR from subprocess popen. **Not write the function, just call it.** Everything I have google keeps bringing me back to how I can write a function from the command line which is NOT what I need.

I need to specifically run a function from subprocess popen so I can get the stdout in a forloop that can then be sent to a flask socket. (This is required)

Main point - How can **Call (not write)** a function from the command line or from subprocess?

Not this:

```
python -c 'import whatever then add code'
```

But something like this:

```
python "test.counttest()"
```

or like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', ".\test.counttest()"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1,universal_newlines=True)
```

EDIT:
This is for @Andrew Holmgren. Consider the following script:

```
def echo(ws):
    data = ws.receive()
    with subprocess.Popen(['powershell', ".\pingtest.ps1"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1,universal_newlines=True) as process:
            for line in process.stdout:
                line = line.rstrip()
                print(line)
                try:
                    ws.send(line+ "\n")
                except:
                    pass
```

this works perfectly for what I need as it:
takes the script's stdout and send's it to the `ws.send()` function which is a websocket.

**However** I need this same concept for a function instead. The **only** way I know how to get the stdout easily is from using `subprocess.popen` but if there is another way let me know. This is why I am trying to make a hackjob way of running a function through the subprocess module.

The question of `Run python function from command line or subprocess popen` relates in the fact that if I can get a function to run from subprocess, then I know how to get the stdout for a websocket.

Comment: You must wait until `test.counttest()` finishes with this code layout: every line is blocking, no parallel execution happens by default. You can make it work with `threading` (or `multiprocessing`, or `asyncio`) library, but it will be really long story. Do you have access to `test.counttest`, can you modify it? If yes, then maybe just make it `yield` every piece of data and iterate over them (without stdout redirection at all)?

Comment: `test.counttest` is just a test script used to have some test printing to the screen every second. The point of `test.counttest` is to test having stdout go to a variable line by line. I tried using yield like you mentioned but nothing happened. Here is the code: ```
def counttest():
    x = 0
    for x in range(0,3):
        x = x+1
        print("Number: "+ str(x))
        time.sleep(1)
        yield "Number: "+ str(x)
```

Comment: I don't exactly follow your example, but consider making a counttest script that imports the test.conttest method. You can then run that script as a subprocess.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren I updated the post for you to give you detail on what I am trying to go for.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have really a lot of questions inside this one.

1. How can I send output of function line-by-line to another one (and/or websocket)? Just avoid writing to stdout and communicate directly. `yield` (or other generator creation methods) are intended exatly for that.

```py
import time

def counttest():
    for i in range(10):
        yield f'Item {i}'
        time.sleep(1)

def echo(ws):
    # data = ws.receive()
    for row in counttest():
        ws.send(row)
```

2. How to call a function `func_name` defined in file (suppose it's `test.py`) from command line? Being in directory with `test.py`, do

```sh
$ python -c 'from test import func_name; func_name()'
```

3. How to read from `sys.stdout`? The easiest will be to replace it with `io.StringIO` and restore thing back later.

```py
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io

def echo(ws):
    f = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        counttest()
    output = f.getvalue()
    ws.send(output)
```

It will return only after `call_function()`, so you cannot monitor real-time printed items.

Regarding

> I need the stdout

I can say, that I'm sure your question is X-Y problem, thus I try to suggest alternatives. Solution you want will also work, but it's awkward. This will exactly run function `counttest` defined in `test.py`, capture its output and send it line-by-line to websocket. It will process output immediately when new line arrives. Note `-u` flag on python call (unbuffered), it's important.

```py
import subprocess
import shlex


def echo(ws):
    data = ws.receive()
    with subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("python -u -c 'from test import counttest; counttest()'"),
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          bufsize=1,
                          universal_newlines=True) as process:
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
            line = line.rstrip()
            if not line:
                break
            print(line)
            try:
                ws.send(line + "\n")
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: I will just delete the account and make a new one with a vpn again. I am clearly not able to communicate properly.

I needed it USING STDOUT. NOT from anything else. the test.countest() was a simple test. In reality the test.countest() is something completely different where I NEED THE STDOUT. 

thank you for your time,

Comment: @SOMUser864839 Is the last point what you expect?